# Dealing with innaccuracy from double arithmetic?

Tags: java, double

I've written a method that tests whether a number is prime or not. To maximise the range of numbers that the user can input, I wanted to use doubles. The issue is, after testing it on a very large prime, like 40 digits or so, my method returns false (I've already tested the logic with an int version, and it works just fine as far as I can tell). 
Here is my code:

```
public static boolean isPrime(double number) {

    double sqrt = Math.sqrt(number);

    for(double i = 2; i<= sqrt; i++) {
        if(number%i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I know the reason it's not working at very high numbers is because of the accuracy error, but is there around this?

Comment: have you considered using BigDecimal?

Comment: Or better [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: Why would you check if a double is a prime number? Primes must be integral. The sqrt is only required to set the upper bound of the highest possible factor.

Comment: don't use doubles for integer operations

Comment: Use long or BigInteger. And never use floating point types when you want to solve integer problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know the reason it's not working at very high numbers is because of the accuracy error, but is there around this?

Yes.  Use `BigInteger`.

Note that `long` would be better than `double`, since `long` can represent all integers up to 2^63 - 1 precisely.  By contrast, with `double` you start losing precision at 2^53 + 1.  However neither of these types are suitable for 40 (decimal) digit numbers.

`BigInteger` arithmetic is significantly slower, but the you will be able to go up to (at least) 2^Integer.MAX_VALUE ... provided that you have enough heap space.